# mmc.exe starts and then immediately stops

Tags: windows-xp, mmc

I'm having a problem where I can't run mmc.exe or any of the programs that depend on it. (services.msc, eventvwr.msc, etc)  If I try to open any of these things, the mouse flickers for a second and then disappears.  If I have task manager running, I can see the mmc.exe pop up in the list of process for about half a second then it goes away. No error messages or anything. Anybody have an idea on what could cause this or how to fix it.

Comment: No UI error messages, or no Windows Events error messages?

Comment: no UI messages.  No idea if there are windows events error messages because I can't open eventvwr

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with Windows itself, or you could be infected with some sort of malware blocking any core utilities from running. Have you tried running them in Administrative mode?

Comment: I'm an administrator if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple machines at the college where I work do this in the last two months.  In both cases is was a malware infection that took out the task manager as well.

Comment: Guess I'll try a scan with spybot and see what it finds